# Discord.js bot missing run method

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I keep getting this error "Error in command basic:sortinghat Error: sortinghat doesn't have a run() method." I've gone through the code for about 10 minutes and changed things for the same result can't seem to find a fix and error log in the console is pointing to where it detects the errors so it isn't helping.

probably an easy fix I promise I'm trying xD

```
const commando = require ('discord.js-commando')


module.exports = class sortinghat extends commando.Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'sortinghat',
            aliases: ['sorting','sortingh'],
            group: 'basic',
            memberName: 'sortinghat',
            description: 'allows you to be sorted into one of the four houses',
        });
    }}

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

    await message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
    const s = message.guild.roles.cach.find('707867871786827776'); //slytherin
    const g = message.guild.roles.cach.find('709348559052603423'); //gryffindor
    const h = message.guild.roles.cach.find('707867828346290256'); //hufflepuff
    const r = message.guild.roles.cach.find('709348458062020660'); //ravenclaw

    const filter = (reaction, user) => ['s', 'g', 'h', 'r'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;

    const embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setTittle('Sorting Hat')
        .setDescription(' Slytherin ${s.toString()} \n Gryffindor ${g.toString()} \n Hufflepuff ${h.toString()} \n Ravenclaw ${r.toString()}')
        .setColor('#fffffd')
        .setFooter('ID: ${message.author.id}');

    message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {
        await message.react(':regional_indicator_s:');
        await message.react(':regional_indicator_g:');
        await message.react(':regional_indicator_h:');
        await message.react(':regional_indicator_r:');

        message.awaitReaction(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 30000,
            errors: ['cant sort at this time']
        }).then(collected => {
            const reaction = collected.first();

            switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                case ':regional_indicator_s':
                    message.member.addRole(s).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                        return message.channel.send('you were sorted into **${s.name}** House!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                        msg.delete();
                    });

                break;
                 case ':regional_indicator_g':
                    message.member.addRole(g).catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                        return message.channel.send('you were sorted into **${s.name}** House!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                        msg.delete();
                    });

                    break;
                    case ':regional_indicator_h':
                        message.member.addRole(h).catch(err => {
                            console.log(err)
                            return message.channel.send('you were sorted into **${s.name}** House!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                            msg.delete();
                        });

                        break;
                        case ':regional_indicator_r':
                            message.member.addRole(r).catch(err => {
                                console.log(err)
                                return message.channel.send('you were sorted into **${s.name}** House!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                                msg.delete();
                            });

                            break;



            }
         }).catch(collected => {
         return message.channel.send('Role not selected or timed out!');
        });

    }
    )}
```

Comment: there's a lot more bugs and bad code than just that, you are not only using discord.js a library, but discord.js-commando a sub library, I really recommend just learning basic js first.

Answer (score 1):

Other guys fixes the problem of the library not finding `.run` but you have a lot of other bugs so here's a quick fix:

````js
module.exports = class sortinghat extends commando.Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'sortinghat',
            aliases: ['sorting', 'sortingh'],
            group: 'basic',
            memberName: 'sortinghat',
            description: 'allows you to be sorted into one of the four houses',
        });
    }

    async run(client, message, args) {
        await message.delete().catch(err => { });
        const roleCache = message.guild.roles.cache;
        const slytherin = roleCache.get('707867871786827776');
        const gryffindor = roleCache.get('709348559052603423');
        const hufflepuff = roleCache.get('707867828346290256');
        const ravenclaw = roleCache.get('709348458062020660');

        const roles = { s: slytherin, g: gryffindor, h: hufflepuff, r: ravenclaw };
        const emojiNames = ["s", "g", "h", "r"];
        const filter = (reaction, user) => emojiNames.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;

        //arguably ugly, change if you want
        const description =
            `Slytherin ${slytherin.toString()}
Gryffindor ${gryffindor.toString()}
Hufflepuff ${hufflepuff.toString()}
Ravenclaw ${ravenclaw.toString()}`;

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setTittle('Sorting Hat')
            .setDescription(description)
            .setColor('#fffffd')
            .setFooter(`ID: ${message.author.id}`);

        const regionalEmote = alpha => `:regional_indicator_${alpha}:`;

        //no clue which message you are referring to at times
        message.channel.send(embed)
            .then(msg => {
                emojiNames.forEach(async alpha => await msg.react(regionalEmote(alpha)));

                return msg.awaitReactions(filter, {
                    max: 1,
                    time: 30000,
                    errors: ["time"]
                });
            })
            .then(collected => {
                const reaction = collected.first();
                //other optoins: slice, get last index
                const alpha = reaction.emoji.name.replace("regional_indicator_", "");
                const selectedRole = roles[alpha];

                message.delete();

                //if you do .then after returning the promise of adding role
                //you wont have access to selectedRole so it's here
                //prob better way but yea
                return message.member.roles.add(selectedRole)
                    .then(() => message.channel.send(`you were sorted into **${selectedRole.name}** House!`));
            })
            .catch(err => message.channel.send('Role not selected or timed out!'));
    }
}```
````

Comment: just keeps telling me message.delete isnt a function but i know it is ;-;

Comment: log what message is then, its possible you are passing another argument as the msg variable like a `Client` instance

Answer (score 0):

`export.run` will not be a method in your `sortinghat` class.

I think you should wrap your `run` method in the class body like that :

```js
module.exports = class sortinghat extends commando.Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'sortinghat',
            aliases: ['sorting','sortingh'],
            group: 'basic',
            memberName: 'sortinghat',
            description: 'allows you to be sorted into one of the four houses',
        });
    }

    async run(client, message, args) {

        await message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
        const s = message.guild.roles.cach.find('707867871786827776'); //slytherin
        const g = message.guild.roles.cach.find('709348559052603423'); //gryffindor
        const h = message.guild.roles.cach.find('707867828346290256'); //hufflepuff
        const r = message.guild.roles.cach.find('709348458062020660'); //ravenclaw

        const filter = (reaction, user) => ['s', 'g', 'h', 'r'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;

        const embed = new RichEmbed()
            .setTittle('Sorting Hat')
            .setDescription(' Slytherin ${s.toString()} \n Gryffindor ${g.toString()} \n Hufflepuff ${h.toString()} \n Ravenclaw ${r.toString()}')
            .setColor('#fffffd')
            .setFooter('ID: ${message.author.id}');

        message.channel.send(embed).then(async msg => {
            await message.react(':regional_indicator_s:');
            await message.react(':regional_indicator_g:');
            await message.react(':regional_indicator_h:');
            await message.react(':regional_indicator_r:');

            message.awaitReaction(filter, {
                max: 1,
                time: 30000,
                errors: ['cant sort at this time']
            }).then(collected => {
                const reaction = collected.first();

                switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                    case ':regional_indicator_s':
                        message.member.addRole(s).catch(err => {
                            console.log(err)
                            return message.channel.send('you were sorted into **${s.name}** House!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                            msg.delete();
                        });

                    break;
                    case ':regional_indicator_g':
                        message.member.addRole(g).catch(err => {
                            console.log(err)
                            return message.channel.send('you were sorted into **${s.name}** House!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                            msg.delete();
                        });

                        break;
                        case ':regional_indicator_h':
                            message.member.addRole(h).catch(err => {
                                console.log(err)
                                return message.channel.send('you were sorted into **${s.name}** House!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                                msg.delete();
                            });

                            break;
                            case ':regional_indicator_r':
                                message.member.addRole(r).catch(err => {
                                    console.log(err)
                                    return message.channel.send('you were sorted into **${s.name}** House!').then(m => m.delete(3000));
                                    msg.delete();
                                });

                                break;
                }
             }).catch(collected => {
             return message.channel.send('Role not selected or timed out!');
            });

        }
    )}
}
```